# Space Symmetry and Conservation of Linear Momentum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, symmetry, conservation-laws, free-body-diagram, noethers-theorem

I am trying to understand Noether's Theorem which links Space Symmetry and Conservation of Linear Momentum from an intuitive perspective.

1. Let's say we have car rolling down a frictionless surface that has a constant slope. Let's say the force of gravity is uniform over the entire surface. If we shift the car along this surface, then we have space symmetry. However, linear momentum is not conserved since the car gets faster. However, if we consider the car-earth system, then linear momentum is conserved.
2. Let's say we have car rolling down a frictionless surface that has a varying slope. If we shift the car along this surface, then we don't have space symmetry. Linear momentum is also not conserved. However, if we consider the car-earth system, then linear momentum is conserved.

I'm a bit confused about how exactly to apply Noether's Theorem.

1. In case 1, we have space symmetry, but we have to consider the car-earth system before linear momentum is conserved.
2. In case 2, space symmetry is not conserved, but linear momentum is conserved in the car-earth system.

Where am going wrong?

Comment: Have you considered that the conservation of momentum requires that momentum is not changing with time (equivalently, that there is not a net force acting on a body)? In this case, momentum is not conserved for the car since gravity is acting on it. Noether’s theorem applies to the symmetries of the action (time integral of the Lagrangian), so this means that your system does not have this symmetry in this case. For this symmetry to exist, you need to actually satisfy Newton’s third law, which will give you a Lagrangian that satisfies this symmetry.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of it is whether or not you are accounting for the finite mass of the slope. After all, the slope pushes on the block via the normal force, and therefore the block also pushes on the slope. If the slope has a finite mass, that means the slope should accelerate in response to the applied force. If you imagine that the slope is *fixed*, then you are effectively treating the slope as if it has an infinite mass. Things tend to go wrong when you put infinity into physics equations.

Another way to say this is that if you treat the slope as having a finite mass, then your Lagrangian should include kinetic energy for the slope as well as interactions between the slope and ball. Once all this is accounted for, linear momentum should be conserved. If you treat the slope as fixed, then it is like having an external potential in the Lagrangian. The external potential breaks the shift symmetry, since a point "to the left" will be at a different height than a point "to the right."

Comment: This reminds me of a physics joke that originated in the 1980's: when Arnold Schwarzenegger does his push-ups he is actually pushing the Earth away from himself.